# What does “completed listing” mean in ebay.com?

Tags: ebay

When searching for items, I see the box on the left as below. What does *completed listing* mean?

[image]

Comment: Alex's answer is correct, but you might wonder why this would be available.  It is useful before you list something of your own so you can know whether people have been buying those items and how much you might be able to get for them.

Comment: Yeah. Knowing the previous number of buyers and how much that costed are very helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A completed listing is a listing that has already resulted in a sale or that has expired with out a sale. In other words, it is no longer an item that can be bought, but the listing remains on eBay showing the final purchase price and winning bidder (if applicable) for 15 days.

[Source](http://ebay.about.com/od/glossaryofebayterms/g/Completed-Listings.htm).